# Apache Spark Streaming Connection String error with Databricks connection to Azure Event Hub

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

I'm getting the error:

```
Exception: ERROR: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_jvm'
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = self.connectionProperties.sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)
```

When I try and call the following function:

```
def EventHubConnectionProperties(self,processId,startOffset,endTime):
        ehConf = {}
        ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = self.connectionProperties.sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)
```

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be used as below -

```
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)
```